# Using mqtt inside lambda function to publish to iot

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-iot

So what I want to do is set a gpio pin on my rpi whenever an s3 bucket adds or deletes a file. I currently have a lambda function set to trigger whenever this occurs. The problem now is getting the function to set the flag. What I currently have in my lambda function is this. But nothing is coming through on my device shadow. My end goal is to have a folder on my rpi stay in sync with the bucket whenever a file is added or deleted without any user input or a cron job.

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='us-west-2')

    # Change topic, qos and payload
    response = client.publish(
        topic='$aws/things/MyThing/shadow/update',
        qos=1,
        json.dumps({"state" : { "desired" : { "switch" : "on" }}})
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the CloudWatch Log for your lambda function, what do it says there?

Since you are intending to update the shadow document, have you tried the function "update_thing_shadow"?